# Get-Acl on a Mapped Drive?

Tags: powershell

Is there a limitation to [`Get-Acl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl?view=powershell-5.1) in that it doesn't work with mapped drives?

When I run it against `C:\Test`, it works fine.  When I run against a mapped drive I get:

```
Get-Acl : Method failed with unexpected error code 50.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Acl U:\Themes
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Acl], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I view the properties of the folder in Explorer, I don't see the security tab.  I thought I could always see the security tab... guess not.

[image: properties screenshot]

Comment: Probably the sec. tab is on the server and not client..

Answer (score 1):

The cmdlet Get-ACL can only operate on drives available to Powershell.
Check your Powershell drives with this cmdlet:

```
Get-PSDrive
```

Add a network drive for Powershell like this:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "Z" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\share1
```

Now Retry:

```
Get-ACL Z:\
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the security tab to show under properties:+
Control Panel>Folder Options>View tab - uncheck "use simple file sharing"

Comment: Doesn't exist in Win10.  I suspect the new value is `Use Sharing Wizard (Recommended)`